# "...ist so einfach nicht." - why this order of words?

Tags: meaning, word-order

Today I'm reading this on the front page of the Neue Zürcher Zeitung:

> [...] Doch ihr Spielraum ist beschränkt, und die Sache mit den Autozöllen ist so einfach nicht.

How is the meaning of this different from the usual "... nicht so einfach." ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

German is very flexible with word orders (much more flexible than English), so you almost always have lots of possibilities to arrange the words within a sentence.

The word order you found is unusual, but allowed. Maybe the author used it to highlight the negation. You often use unusual (but still correct) word orders to put the focus on a special part of speech within a sentence.

The word *»nicht«* is very special when talking about word order. You can put it almost everywhere in the sentence, but you have to be careful, because this sometimes can change the meaning.

As a rule of thumb: Put the word *»nicht«* as close as possible to the part of speech that you want to negate.

The position of *nicht* within a sentence is topic of many questions here on german.stackexchange. You can find more information about this topic here: [Position of *nicht*](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=nicht%20position)

Comment: Also, at least to me this construction sounds like an archaisation (if that word exists)

Comment: @Philipp: I don't know if this word exists. But I know, that I don't know it, and my favorite dictionary (dict.leo.org) also doesn't know it. And therefore I did not understand your comment.

Comment: I meant that the word order in OP’s example is correct but oldfashioned, in a willfully constructed (unnatural) way of speaking, and that it is supposed to sound a little archaic (but it really isn’t because we’re living today, not in ancient times). I’m not trying to say it’s good or bad style. I use this expression sometimes, jokingly. It’s just not (at least in my language) a common wording, not even when I want to stress something in all seriousness.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to the usual version

> X ist nicht so einfach

does

> X ist so einfach nicht[, wie man denkt]

stronger imply the subtext, that one would expect that X is easy to do.